# Animate multiple path with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, raphael

I would like to draw dynamically multiple paths but my issue is when the first path is drawed he is removed before create the other one.

here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/symro/ds4kj/2/

and my animate function

```
animateLine:function(canvas, pathString,attr){
            var line = canvas.path(pathString);
            var length = line.getTotalLength();

            console.dir(line);

            $('#canvas_map').animate({
                'to': 1
            }, {
                duration: 2500,
                step: function(pos, fx) {
                    var offset = length * fx.pos;
                    var subpath = line.getSubpath(0, offset);
                    canvas.clear();
                    canvas.path(subpath).attr(attr);
                },
            });
            return canvas;
    }
```

Comment: because on animate function you clear the canvas with canvas.clear()

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! But now i got an another issue, my paths are pixelated. Do you know why ?
My new jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/symro/ds4kj/5/

Comment: I think its a good question, but may be better put in a separate thread.

Comment: Your paths are pixelated because you have too many points. You need to simplify your paths and they will become smooth.